# Дополнительно выделить память для динамического массива C

Tags: c, массивы, строки, указатели, память

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: есть строка, которая хранится в динамическом массиве определённого размера, и мне нужно определённое количество раз увеличить объём памяти под массив ровно на один дополнительный элемент. Могу ли я каким-то образом сделать это "расширение" без предварительного копирования содержимого массива?

```
    char* s;
    s = (char*)malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
    s[0] = '2';
    s[1] = '\0';
    s = (char*)malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
    printf_s("Строка : %s", s);
```

Хотелось бы реализовать на чистом C

Comment: [man realloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc)

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Нет, этого сделать нельзя.

Comment: если считать, что автор вопроса имеет ввиду "без явного копирования", то да, realloc поможет (он делает копирование по необходимости).

Comment: Увеличение "несколько раз на один элемент" - не эффективнее ли увеличивать, скажем, в два раза, с запасом? Тогда и амортизированная стоимость копирования одного символа становится константной...

Comment: домашние задания бывают безжалостны и беспощадны. Пора уже добавлять метку "так хочет преподаватель"

Comment: @Harry, я пока, к сожалению, не знаю, как оставлять комментарии кому-то конкретному, поэтому напишу так. Да, можно было и так, но я решил написать простенький брутфорс с помощью рекурсии и мне нужно было именно увеличение на один символ, чтоб не потреблять лишней памяти

Comment: а в результате, скорее всего, из-за фрагментации может получаться только хуже, особенно при большом количестве запросов небольшого размера. Впрочем, это зависит от конкретного менеджера памяти, но эффективность в смысле времени работы снижается основательно - выделение памяти не такая уж дешевая процедура, а с учетом еще и копирования... Кстати, какие у вас *реальные* размеры? При сотнях байт заморачиваться экономией памяти смешно, при мегабайтах копирование (пусть даже неявное) будет занимать массу времени...

Comment: @Harry, не более 15 символов пока. Для чего я это всё затеял-то. Решил попрактиковаться и попробовать написать простенький брутфорс с заданной максимальной длинной пароля. Вот и добавляю каждый раз по одному символу в строку

Comment: Выделите сразу для 15 символов и не мучьтесь... Все равно, подозреваю, менеджер памяти будет выделять не 1-2-3 байта, а сразу байт 16 как минимум :)

Comment: @Harry, да, я это же решил уже. И программа стала работать быстрее, спасибо!

Comment: @Harry И насколько существенно будет ускорение/замедление?

Comment: @Mikhailo, ну вот я поменял и у меня при максимальной длине пароля в 3 символа вместо 5 секунд стало 4, а вот уже при длине в 5 символов - вместо 5 минут стало 2:20-2:40 (В зависимости от символов, входящих в пароль)